# How do I locate a dryer exhaust vent?

Tags: vent, dryer, locating

I live in an older duplex. I just recently attempted to clean out the dryer vent/duct for the downstairs unit and failed because I could not find where my dryer vent is outside. Is it possible that my dryer vent and the upstairs dryer vents are connected to the same outdoor vent?

Answer (score 1):

Place a wet towel in your dryer, turn it on, and in 5 minutes look for the steam somewhere around your house.

Comment: I have done that. I can't find it anywhere. I can see the upstairs unit vent & the steam when they have their dryer running. I bought a lint cleaner device & I could not get it to go all the way through the duct, I got quit a bit of lint out though. But was starting to think that maybe because I could not get the lint snake to go all the way through to the outdoor hole that, it may be clogged now??

Comment: BMitch do you have any other suggestions? Do you think that it is possible that both upstairs & downstairs share the same outdoor dryer exhaust??

Comment: Does vent go into the floor or through a wall?

Comment: Through the wall

Comment: Have you checked your attic? Sometimes dryers are (incorrectly) vented there.

Comment: I don't have an attic...I live in a duplex...& I am in the bottom unit

Comment: You're not supposed to connect the vents together since one dryer could then exhaust out the other dryer, so you should have another exhaust somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible an earlier repair/renovation blocked the dryer vent.  See if you can trace the duct from the basement to see where it used to go.